# How compare the overall performance of two .net console applications?

Tags: .net, performance

I have 2 .net console apps that solve the same problem(using different algorithms). How to compare their overall performance: time (not affected by system load), total memory/cpu usage etc..

Answer (score 0):

Maybe use JetBrains dotTrace profiler for .NET applications, it has 10 days free trial. https://www.jetbrains.com/profiler/download/

Comment: Any idea how to obtain some stable metric from Profiler that can be compared?

Comment: Because the total time taken by both apps is affected by a external factor: the current system load. I can't rely on it to determine which algorithm is faster. It can compromise the results.